# VBA - Copying Data with Autofilter into multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, format, copy, autofilter

I have a macro that, from one worksheet, copies and seperates data, depending on their value in a certain column, into multiple worksheets based on an autofilter. After doing so, I format all sheets into a table. But because there are also other worksheets (always with the names "Such..." and "Tabelle...") in these workbooks, I want to exclude these when doing my worksheet loop. Here is the VBA:

```
Sub TechfelderBlätter()

Dim i As Integer
Set Eingaben = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Eingaben")
Set MainWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Eingaben.Cells(3, 3).Value)

LastRow = MainWS.Range((Eingaben.Cells(4, 3).Value) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
TFS = Eingaben.Cells(12, 3).Value
myarray = uniqueValues(MainWS.Range(TFS & "2:" & TFS & LastRow))

    For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
        
        TFname = Left(myarray(i), 30)
        
        Sheets.Add.Name = TFname
        MainWS.Range("A1:" & TFS & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=myarray(i)
        MainWS.Range("A1:" & TFS & LastRow).Cells.Copy _
            Sheets(Left(myarray(i), 30)).Range("A1")
        MainWS.Range("A1:" & TFS & LastRow).AutoFilter
            Sheets(TFname).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
            Sheets(TFname).ListObjects.Add.Name = TFname & "_Table"
            Sheets(TFname).ListObjects(TFname & "_Table").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight11"
    Next i

    MainWS.Activate
    MainWS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
    MainWS.ListObjects.Add.Name = MainWS.Name & "_Table"
    MainWS.ListObjects(MainWS.Name & "_Table").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight11"

End Sub

Private Function uniqueValues(InputRange As Range)
    
Dim cell As Range
Dim tempList As Variant: tempList = ""
    
    For Each cell In InputRange
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "/", " ")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "\", " ")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "?", " ")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "*", " ")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "[", " ")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "]", " ")
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, tempList, cell.Value) = 0 Then
                If tempList = "" Then tempList = Trim(CStr(cell.Value)) Else tempList = tempList & "|" & Trim(CStr(cell.Value))
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    uniqueValues = Split(tempList, "|")
    
End Function
```

Problem1: The cell formatting, specifically the column width, does not get copied, resulting in most columns in the new worksheets being too narrow.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I apologise if its a messy code, I know using activate and select isn´t good, but I didn´t know how else to code it.

Edit: I have solved one of the problems. The problem was: The Autofilter command is not dynamic because of the "Field:=16". Ideally, I would like to replace "16" with the TFS variable, in which the column letter is typed in by hand, in this case "P".

Comment: Use Power Query my friend

Comment: If it were only this, I may have tried Power Query. But given this is part of a larger macro, in which VBA is best for the other parts, I believe it makes most sense sticking with VBA for this as well...

Comment: I believe using Power Query and changing your macro would make more sense. You can refresh your Power Query via VBA

Comment: Solution to Problem1 - add "Sheets(TFname).Columns("A:" & TFS).EntireColumn.AutoFit" - above "Next i"

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with by myself now. Instead of:

```
MainWS.Range("A1:" & TFS & LastRow).Cells.Copy _
            Sheets(Left(myarray(i), 30)).Range("A1")
```

I now use this:

```
TFname = Left(myarray(i), 30)
    MainWs.Range("A1:" & TFS & LastRow).Cells.Copy
            With Sheets(TFname).Range("A1")
                                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
                                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
            End With
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).